# My custom login form in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, authentication, admin

By the custom form in WordPress I don't think on customizing WP login form. I've made my own login form in custom-page.php (WP) and I want my users login in on my own page custom-admin.php or custom-user.php. And I don't want my users have any connection with my wp-admin. That's my area. And also I have my table my_user in wp database. Is there some plugin for that or I have to do everything form scratch (login.php,logout.php,admin.php)? Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-custom-register-login/

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can do that, I don't know about plugin, but I have created like this case before.

What I did :

Create custom page template for login page, dashboard page, etc.
please see this https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

Then you should read this too to make authenticate users
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon

but `wp_signon` of course will work only using default WordPress users table. It will not work with your custom `my_user` table. And if I were you, I will use default WordPress users table so I can have all WordPress features and functions for the users.

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include more of the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.